# Why modifying cookies synchronously during page rendering does not affect further GET requests made during page load?

Tags: http, cookies, synchronization, html, specifications

It was a big surprise for me to find out, that cookies are not being attached to further synchronous requests on the page, in case when they are set synchronously within  tag.

Example:

```
<head>
  <script>
    document.cookie='foo=bar; path=/'
  </script>
  <script src="/service/dynamic_js_controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
```

In this case when I open this page first time in incognito session, "foo" cookie is being set, then it synchronously requests and retrieves /service/dynamic_js_controller.js, but this GET request has empty "Cookie" request header.

It will only have those cookies attached to the request headers if I reload this page.
It feels like cookies snapshot is made once during page load, and further cookie changes do not affect this snapshot.

Can anyone please explain what is exactly happening??
Is that consistent for all user agents?